# Angular inside a polymer template with auto-binding

Tags: angularjs, polymer, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use angular ui router with core-animated-pages. Right now I'm stuck because if I include the ui-views inside the sections of a core-animated-pages element, and all of that is inside a `<template is="auto-binding">` element, then the transition works but angular does not fill the ui-views. I think it because the `template` makes it all part of the shadow dom.

Here's a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/tYyuKLO1O5JQVtpNg9Th?p=preview

Thanks.

Comment: Ha! I see you are having the same issue now. I was looking at the other  question you asked and thought of using `<template is="auto-binding">` but then I couldn't figure out how to render the views properly so I offered a none data binding solution. Anyway, I too look forward to the answer!

Comment: Nice to hear someone else is interested. I'm going to try keeping it in angular later tonight - http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2014/12/19/angular-hero-transitions.html

Comment: @JustinXL check it out! Keeping the animations in polymer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong - you don't have to use `template`.

And here's how you do it!
https://github.com/morgs32/angular-polymer